# (Android) Is there any way to start App from HeadlessJS React Native when App is not running?

Tags: react-native, service, headless

This is problem on Android. I want to start App from HeadlessJS service (this service invoked when a notification arrived).
When App in background mode, it's ok. I used NativeModule to call startActivity(). But when App is killed, this startActivity() call doesn't work. The App seem started but in paused mode. It doesn't appear.

I google alot but not found any solution.
Currently, my native code to startActivity is below.

```java
        @ReactMethod
    public void startApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(), getCurrentActivity().getClass());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library satisfy me:

https://github.com/lvlrSajjad/react-native-launch-application.

Work on my android device but I will test it on more devices.